# Can we remove zesty distribution from our sources.list files in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS(trusty) servers. I do patch my servers every month using apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade commands. For few days these updates were failing with 404 not found errors. Close look on the /etc/apt/sources.list file and the error message revealed that the following lines in the sources.list file were causing the issue:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe multiverse

# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe multiverse
```

I have removed these lines from /etc/apt/sources.list file for now and apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade commands seems to be working fine now. I don't remember adding these lines in the /etc/apt/sources.list file by myself. So any idea what might have added these lines in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? Are these lines required in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 lines were added to the sources.list file to upgrade openssh to fix a vulnerability. Hence those 2 lines shouldn't have been part of the sources.list file since the distro for Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS is trusty. Hence removing those 2 lines from the sources.list file is perfectly fine.